I need to know what I should answer as ACK to a GPS tracker protocol named TQ
I'm trying to develop a new WinForm App to receive data from a Chinese GPS tracker.
The packets are like this

*HQ,1054115795,V6,151202,V,3534.2406,S,5939.5911,W,0.00,268.00,290424,FFFFFBFF,727,07,4508,103224127,8954079900016945393F,#

It seems that is waiting for some ACK because it reports every 40 seconds, it doesn't matter how the timers are set; but can't find any info about.
Any help about this would be appreciated.
